# How to train SVM with SIFT feature?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a newbie in Opencv. Can anybody give me a brief step by step description about how to train SVM with SIFT feature in OpenCV? I obtained the keypoints from image usinf SIFT. But I am not understanding how to train SVM classifier with this keypoints? If I do need to create vector from this keypoints, how to create vector from keypoints?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: the problem is, that you'll need the same amount of features as SVM input for each sample, but you probably won't have the same number of keypoints for each sample. Have a look at "bag of words" method with SVM.

Comment: http://kushalvyas.github.io/BOV.html